# Javascript in php variable (hide on click)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

These are the buttons i am outputing on my index.php page from my search.php page:

```
    $text = '<button id="Da" class="btn btn-success btn-large lineheightsearch greenbutton"><i class="icon-white icon-ok whiteiconimportant"></i>Želim oddati povpraševanje</button><button id="Ne"class="btn btn-success btn-large lineheightsearch"><i class="icon-white icon-remove whiteiconimportant"></i>Ne hvala</button>';
```

This is the div on my index page i am trying to hide with the click on these php echoed buttons:

```
div id="kategorije"
```

And this is the script i want to use.

```
 <script>
$( "#Da" ).click(function() {
  $( "#kategorije" ).hide( "slow" );
});
</script>
```

Where do I have to put this script? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You put that script on the page.. Or in a JS file that is referenced from the page... I'm having difficulties understanding exactly what you're asking here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $( "#Da" ).click(function() {
      $( "#kategorije" ).hide( "slow" );
   });

});

</script>

<?php


$text = '<button id="Da" class="btn btn-success btn-large lineheightsearch greenbutton"><i class="icon-white icon-ok whiteiconimportant"></i>Želim oddati povpraševanje</button><button id="Ne"class="btn btn-success btn-large lineheightsearch"><i class="icon-white icon-remove whiteiconimportant"></i>Ne hvala</button>';

echo $text;
?>

<div id="kategorije">text</div>
```